# Function pointer in c (effect of address and reference operator on a function)

Tags: c, types, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function call with different semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179689/function-call-with-different-semantics)

I am reading about function pointers in C. I tried this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void)
{
    printf("At foo.");
    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("%p\t%p\t%p\n", &foo, foo, *foo);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this program is:

```
0040138C    0040138C    0040138C
```

In 1-D array `<datatype> <identifier>[N]`, `identifier` and `&identifier` points to the same value but the nature of the values are different. One is of type `datatype*` and the other is of type pointer to the 1-D array. Analogously, for functions, the `foo` and `&foo` are the same. But what about `*foo` and what is the nature of `&foo, foo, *foo`?

Comment: yes, :D, [for fun try (**********foo)()]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain `foo` is already a function pointer:

> 6.3.2.1 - 4
>
> A function  designator is  an  expression  that  has  function  type.
>   Except  when  it  is  the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary
>   & operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning
>   type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘**pointer to
>   function returning type**’’.

You may obtain the address of a function using `&`, which yields a `pointer to function ...`:

> 6.5.3.1 - 1-3
>
> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function
>   designator... The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.
>   If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
>   **the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’**

**It's legal** to apply the indirection operator to a function designator:

> 6.5.3.2 - 3
>
> The unary * operator denotes indirection. **If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function  designator**

tldr:

So there you have it. They all do the same thing.

---

#### EDIT

> What is 'function type` in C

Quick! To the standard!

> 6.2.5 - 1
>
> Types are  partitioned  into object  types (types  that  describe 
>   objects)  and function  types (types that describe functions).
>
> 6.2.5 - 20
>
> **A function type describes a function with speciﬁed return type**. A
>   function type is characterized  by  its  return  type  and  the 
>   number  and  types  of  its  parameters. A function type is said to be
>   derived from its return type, and if its return type is T, the
>   function  type  is  sometimes  called  ‘‘function  returning T’’. The 
>   construction  of  a function type from a return type is called
>   ‘‘function type derivation’’

Comment: What is 'function type` and how does it reflect returning function's address via indirection?

Comment: I find it complex to understand the terminology used in spec. .function designator means the label used to identify the function? (in this case foo)

Comment: @ram If you find it difficult than you should write more programs before delving into standard nitpicking questions. **I.e. write useful stuff as opposed to printing `foo`, `&foo` and `*foo`**.

Comment: @cnicutar: While i was reading function pointers, i came across invoking functions implicitly and explicitly. That is (*fnptr)() and fnptr() both will work where 'fnptr' points to some function. With intuition the reference operator has no effect on functions. So i started experimenting a bit more and this question is a by-product of it. I was being curious. My point is you should encourage people when they are nosy as it lets them know new things. Any way thank you for your answer as it solves some of my questions.

Comment: @ram You're right but you should also be prepared to read the spec. You might also be interested in http://www.newty.de/fpt/

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ a function can be used only in 2 ways: you can take its address and you can call it. You cannot do anything else with it.

So, `foo` is a function itself. C++ has a standard conversion `4.3 Function-to-pointer conversion`. This means that `foo` will be automatically converted to `&foo`. Notation `&&&&foo` results in a syntax error.

In C++ `5.3.1.1 Unary operators` there is wording that allows dereferencing function pointers with the result of the function itself. This implies that multiple `*`'s should not be allowed. Nevertheless they work at least in MSVC and GCC. Maybe this is so because compiler applies `Function-to-pointer conversion` immediately after dereferencing before processing the next operation.

I do not see good reasoning for allowing multiple `*`'s and not allowing multiple `&`'s with functions. For some reason different logic is implemented for `*` and `&` operations.

You can try to cast `foo` to `char*` and dereference this pointer. It will contain bytes of the machine code. The length of these bytes is unknown. Read/write protection of this address is unknown too. Many CPU architectures allow setting execute bit without setting read and write bits. So, you can call the function but an attempt to read at this address may result in a crash.

Comment: @Kobelev, I have read that function identifier will automatically decay to a function pointer in almost all cases except it with sizeof operator or reference operator. Hence as &foo is already a l-value you cannot apply reference operator on it again. &&foo results in error. Further, as you mentioned "compiler applies Function-to-pointer conversion immediately after dereferencing before processing the next operation" hence ****foo works alright. About the address, i am assuming it is the address to which the CPU jumps to execute the routine.

Comment: You know, honestly I do not see a deep logic here. For me this is more a set of random decisions that are mimicked by different compilers in the same way. There is not a lot of what we can do with functions. I tend to accept the situation without attempts of logical explanation.

Comment: Standard is not saying that the value of the function pointer is an address of an entry point. Compiler is free to put there whatever it wants. At the same time, realistically speaking, it is hard to imagine that there will be something else.

Comment: Do you see any value in allowing `****foo`? I do not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673848/set-a-function-pointer-to-a-static-address?rq=1. This links points that the address of a function pointer is the entry point.

Comment: having said that increasing the function pointer by unit 1 does not necessarily point to the next instruction as partial code might be placed at some location as part of opt.